# How to compare 2 large txt files

Tags: comparison

I have 2 txt documents, they are not formated the same way. But I know for sure one of them have some copy pasta from the other one.

Is there any tool to find these copied sentences?
I have tried some compare tool online, but it's almost line-to-line comparition :\

Comment: You are a teacher? :-) I would first eliminate all returns, making both files into a big single line. Then I would insert a newline after all "`.`". So all sentences would start in a new line. Then I would compare them by the `diff` tool. But this solution probably does not what you want to. I hope you get an answer what you want.

Comment: What OS should it run on? What's your price margin should it come to paid solutions? Apart from that: Basically what peter wrote. One such diff tool that would probably fit fine is [meld](https://meldmerge.org/) (see the screenshots on its site). It's available for most platforms (from the package systems in Linux distris, for Mac, even for the niche system called Windows). You'd probably not even need the "sentence separation" with meld. But yes, such "diff tools" work sequential; you might rather be after something like "plagiate scanners"?

Comment: @izzy yeah, that is the problem. Thanks both of you. I am working on a node.js script that will smartly check every "clone" that match more that X words (I will change x to change the precision needs). So far the script take too long and ends up exploding lol. Still working on it

Comment: Node.js? Brrr… ("Jeho…") I wouldn't expect a different outcome than "exploding", true #D OK, good luck then – when it comes to monsters, I rather hide under my blanket :D

Comment: I am limited by my knowledge :( I think what I'm trying to do requires that I learn some real stuff like C